# Salesforce login link not loading login page using frames

Tags: html, salesforce, frames, frameset

I am experiencing quiet an unusual issue with salesforce when I put it in a html frame, when I click on the login button link, it is not loading the login page. but every other link is working perfectly fine, as soon as I take it out of the html frame it works, is there something that can be done to fix this issue by any chance? I have looked and been unsuccessful.

So i got 2 .html files 1 named Script, which is just plain simple text to be displayed in the left frame, and the main frame is the salesforce link.

Then the third html file is the frame file which links both html files to load into one.

The code for all this is below, please let me know if you are successful, Thanks.

script.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60; url=script.html" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Script</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p> hello how are you </p>
</body>
</html>
```

salesForce.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.salesforce.com/au/" />
<title>Sales Force</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

salesForceScript.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Sales Force & Script</title>
</head>

<frameset rows="*" cols="277*,973*" framespacing="0" frameborder="no" border="0">
  <frame src="script.html" name="leftFrame" id="leftFrame" title="leftFrame" />
  <frame src="salesForce.html" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" title="mainFrame" />
</frameset>
<noframes>
<body>

</body>
</noframes>
</html>
```

Comment: This might be caused by XSS protection setting in your SFDC org.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate a little bit, will using frames give me the ability to navigate and manipulate a site without any issues, or does it happen because im like crossing domains?